Not able to set cookies correctly in next js front end app using Fast APIs

Back end is developed using python Fast APIs and running on http://127.0.0.1:9000.
Front end is developed using typescript NextJS framework (v 14.2.3) and running on http://localhost:3000. Opted App Router and app directory. Using axios library to call APIs.

I am trying to set cookies from API in front end app which is running in different domain from back end. The cookies are setting like this in browser ->
Screenshot of browser inspection tools of cookies
Screenshot of browser inspection tools of API call Response headers in network
When I reload the app manually, the cookies are automatically removed from browser. And I am also not able to access these cookies inside the front end NextJS code.
In Back end code:
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["http://localhost:3000"],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

# login API =======================================>>>>>>>>>>>
@router.post("/login", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    response: Response,
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()],
    db: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(async_get_db)],
) -> Dict[str, str]:
    user = await authenticate_user(
        username_or_email=form_data.username, password=form_data.password, db=db
    )
    if not user:
        raise UnauthorizedException("Wrong username, email or password.")

    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = await create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user["username"]}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )

    refresh_token = await create_refresh_token(data={"sub": user["username"]})
    max_age = settings.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DAYS * 24 * 60 * 60

    response.set_cookie(
        key="refresh_token",
        value=refresh_token,
        httponly=False,
        secure=False,
        samesite="Lax",
        max_age=max_age,
    )
    response.set_cookie(
        key="access_token",
        value=f"Bearer {access_token}",
        httponly=False,
        secure=False,
        samesite="Lax",
        max_age=max_age,
    )

    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

Front end code (calling login API):
http.ts file ===============>>>>>>>>>>>
import axios from "axios";

const Post = (url: string, requestPayload: any, credentials: boolean = false) => {

    return axios
        .post(url, requestPayload, {
            withCredentials: credentials,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
        })

}

const HTTP = { Post };

export default HTTP;

login/page.tsx ===================>>>>>>>>>
'use client'

import { Button, Divider } from "@nextui-org/react";
import TypeInput from "../formUtils/typeInput";
import { UserLoginModelType } from "../models/AuthModel";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { UserLoginFormValidations } from "./services/LoginFormValidations";
import { Logo } from "../icons/Logo";
import { LogoText } from "../icons/LogoText";
import Link from "next/link";
import { HiOutlineMail } from "react-icons/hi";
import { MdLockOutline } from "react-icons/md";
import TypePassword from "../formUtils/typePassword";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch } from "../redux/store";
import { setTokenFromCookie } from "../redux/features/auth-slice";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import ToastMessage from "../components/toastMessage";
import HTTP from "../utils/http";

const Login = () => {

    const router = useRouter();
    const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

    const {
        control,
        handleSubmit,
        reset,
        register,
        formState: { isValid },
        watch,
        setValue,
    } = useForm<UserLoginModelType>();

    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<UserLoginModelType> = async (data) => {
        toast.remove(); // remove all previous toast messages
        const formData = new URLSearchParams();
        formData.append("username", data.username);
        formData.append("password", data.password);
        HTTP.Post(`http://127.0.0.1:9000/auth/login`, formData, true).then(async (resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
            const responseData = resp.data;
            console.log(responseData);
            if (resp) {
                router.push("/dashboard");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const cookie = Cookies.get("access_token");
                    dispatch(setTokenFromCookie({ access_token: cookie || "" }));
                }, 500)
                toast.custom((t) => (<ToastMessage message="Logged in successfully." t={t} />));
            } else {
                toast.custom((t) => (<ToastMessage toastType="error" message={responseData.detail || "Cannot login."} t={t} />));
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error::::::::", error);
            const errorResp = error.response?.data;
            toast.custom((t) => (<ToastMessage toastType="error" message={errorResp?.detail || error.message} t={t} />));
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center overflow-y-auto">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="max-h-full flex flex-col gap-6 rounded-lg border-[0.5px] border-borderColor1/50 p-8 overflow-y-auto">
                <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                    <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-4">
                        <Logo width={25} height={25} />
                        <LogoText size={100} />
                    </div>
                    <Divider orientation="vertical" />
                    <div className="font-semibold text-md">
                        Dashboard
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Divider />
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <TypeInput
                        name="username"
                        control={control}
                        rules={UserLoginFormValidations.username}
                        label="Username"
                        type="text"
                        required={true}
                        startContent={<HiOutlineMail size={20} />}
                        size="md"
                    />
                    <TypePassword
                        name="password"
                        control={control}
                        rules={UserLoginFormValidations.password}
                        label="Password"
                        required={true}
                        startContent={<MdLockOutline size={20} />}
                        size="md"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 items-space justify-between items-center">
                    <Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="solid" >
                        Login
                    </Button>
                    <Link href="/resetpassword" className="text-sm text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700">Forgot password? Reset here.</Link>
                    <Link href="/signup" className="text-sm text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700">Don't have account? Register here.</Link>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;

Trying with this, I wanted to set cookies from back end API in front end. The cookies are setting but I am not able to access cookies inside NextJS application. And also, the cookies are removed when I reload the page.
I changed my back-end domain to localhost (URL: http://localhost:9000), then the cookies are staying.
My requirement is I want to keep back end and front end in separate domains (no matter what domain they are on, either same or different) and set cookies from API to front end and. I need to access those cookies inside front end. And the cookies should stay until explicitly deleted in front end.

I guess the issue is with your cookie domain as it should be localhost:3000 or whatever your FE domain is instead of your BE domain which is 127.0.something..
try setting your domain while setting the cookie and hope that your issue will be solved:
response.set_cookie(
        key="access_token",
        value=f"Bearer {access_token}",
        httponly=False,
        secure=False,
        samesite="Lax",
        max_age=max_age,
        domain="localhost"  # Set your domain here
    )


Tried this. Since the backend is running on 127.0.0.1, if I set domain="localhost", the cookies are not setting in front end when I hit the API.

okay then I'll let you know if I figure something out
